# IIS Application pools CLR v4.0 vs No managed code

Tags: iis, iis-8, application-pool

I am currently developing an app which uses .NET Core.

I have hosted a lot of micro-services on IIS Manager in a new app pool.

Is there any advantage for an app pool version instead of the latest .NET CLR v4.0, to use no managed code?

I heard some things that no managed code option gets better performance. Is that true?

Answer (score 17):

You should use "No managed code" if only an ASP.NET Core app is hosted:

> ASP.NET Core runs in a separate process and manages the runtime. ASP.NET Core doesn't rely on loading the desktop CLR (.NET CLR). The Core Common Language Runtime (CoreCLR) for .NET Core is booted to host the app in the worker process. Setting the .NET CLR version to No Managed Code is optional but recommended.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: What is the consequence of NOT setting "No managed code"?

Comment: @Pawel you are asking for trouble.

Comment: No, I am genuinely looking for an answer. I want to make my app always running on the IIS as it needs to run background tasks. A couple of solutions are asking to change back to .NET CLR Version v4.0 hence my question. https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html#making-asp-net-core-application-always-running-on-iis

Comment: Again, running background tasks is asking for more trouble.

Comment: Thanks, Can you update this link, as only the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 has the related content, the newest one version don't. It may cause confused

Comment: @lexi might you elaborate on "running background tasks is asking for more trouble"... I've been using HF for many years both .net and netcore ...  42.6M downloads on nuget... plus am currently working on a netcore app that essentially uses a number of BackgroundService and IHostedService... implementations. So (considering that not all netcore web apps are GUI/user focused) am wondering if you might expand (I know this is old, but interested in your opinions). Interested to hear more on your view on this.

Comment: Also the doc you linked to says "Setting the .NET CLR version to No Managed Code is optional but recommended" Seems to me that if you choose to let IIS load the Desktop CLR etc... it's maybe NOT the end of the world. Obviously I wouldn't bother unless I (like Pawel) wanted to get HF to keep running through IIS recycles etc... but is it the end of the world?